# Certain set is closed when $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ is a metric space and we have equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, nets

Hi I want to see if this I am doing this right.

Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff, $Y$ is a metric space, and $\langle f_n\rangle$ is equicontinuous.

Show that $$C=\{x\in X: \langle f_n(x)\rangle \text{ is a cauchy sequence in $Y$}\}$$
is closed.

Proof: Suppose that $\langle x_\alpha\rangle\subset C$ is a net that converges to $x$ and let $d$ be the metric on $Y$. Then 
$$d(f_n(x),f_m(x))\leq d(f_n(x),f_n(x_\alpha))+d(f_n(x_\alpha),f_m(x_\alpha))+d(f_m(x_\alpha),f_m(x))$$ for any $\alpha,n,m$.

So if I fix an $\epsilon$, the first and last terms can be controlled by equicontinuity: I can produce a $U$ such that each is less that $\epsilon/2$. Then pick an element in the net that satisfies this condition. Now, since $\alpha$ is fixed I can use the cauchy condition on $x_\alpha$.

Is this correct? This is a prelim problem and so this argument seems suspiciously too easy.

Comment: What is a prelimit?

Comment: Your argument is correct. the question is quite trivial.

Comment: A problem from a quals exam.

Comment: Presumably, the $f_n$ are functions $X\to Y$. That is something you really ought to specify explicitly.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Not prelimit problem, but prelim problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelims .